# Amazon Beanstalk correct place for logs of Windows IIS application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is correct place to store logs in Amazon Beanstalk Windows IIS website?

We need them not to be deleted during application republish.

Answer (score 0):

As for solution we are using now, we are storing logs in App_Data/logs and at the same time publishing them to logentries. This solution was not tested under production load yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about application logs (e.g. using Log4Net):

What currently use GrayLog as Log Server (dedicated Linux machine) and we publish the application logs from our environments to this dedicated log server that offers plenty of log analysis tools.